# Webapi Set a delay between requests and queue them

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, f#, asp.net-core-webapi

I guess there may be a simple way to do this, but I have an API that I need to "stagger" requests coming in because of a separate API that has rate limiting on it.

So - we would receive requests through a controller and the controller would put requests in order and only send off to the second api once every second. Something like a message queue? ( I am not familiar with those yet ) .  The following is written in F# but C# answers are all good.

```
[<ApiController>]
[<Route("[controller]")>]
type WeighScanController (logger : ILogger<WeighScanController>) =
    inherit ControllerBase()


    [<HttpGet>]
    member _.Get(orderNumber: string, weight: decimal, carrierServiceOverride: string, orderNumberSuffix: string ) = task {
        if orderNumber<> null && weight <> 0m then
            let suffix = 
                match orderNumberSuffix with
                | null -> ""
                | _ -> orderNumberSuffix

            // the following line can only be called once every second    
            let! result =  WeighScanM2.weighScanM2(orderNumber,weight,carrierServiceOverride, suffix)
            return result
        else
            return "Incorrect Values Passed"
    }
```

Comment: Before hitting the controller, every request made hits the [ActionFilterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionfilterattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0). You can create a class which is inheriting from ActionFilterAttribute, and give the request a delay time here. And then use this class at the class level of controller.

Comment: Thanks @chen  but if I just create a delay how will I know how one request relates to other requests?  they need to be queued and run in order and spaced apart.

Comment: I think each request can be regarded as a task, and then [create a queue service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/queue-service?pivots=dotnet-7-0) for these tasks, and use this service in ActionFilterAttribute.